# How to put values of a form in an object and send the object to controller

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have a jsp form that is used to submit the details of users to an action, 
As I do not want the action class extends the user class, I need to create an object of the inputs and send it to my action, but not sure how.

- User class has a long list of parameters, if I extend it I should have all of them as parameters of my Register method.

Form

```
     <s:form action="Register">

                <s:textfield name="fname" label="Name"/>
                <s:textfield name="lname" label="Surname"/>
                <s:textfield name="mobile" label="Mobile"/>
                   .....
                <s:submit validate="true"></s:submit>
    </s:form>

 <jsp:useBean id="obj" class="com.Users"/>
 <jsp:setProperty property="*" name="obj"/>
```

Action

```
  @Action
  public class Registration{
    public boolean Register(User obj)
    {
           .....
    }
    ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Pojo class of all the fields and by getParameter() method you can set the value corresponding to each field of Pojo class. After that you can directly pass the Pojo class obj to your Registration method directly.

Comment: check the configuration file where you may set <forward action> value that should be set to index.jsp.